# how create custom labels on a circular line chart

Tags: r, date, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to figure out how to plot data on weekly basis while having labels on circular axis for months only.

This topic is partly covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41081376/how-to-create-a-circular-plot-showing-monthly-presence-or-absence-using-radial-p) but the data they have there is structurally different.

I have a dataset with number of posts posted per week:

```r
   id week posts   weekdate year month  col fct_month
1:  1    1    26 2001-01-01 2001     1 grey       Jan
2:  2    2    24 2001-01-08 2001     1 grey       Jan
3:  3    3    35 2001-01-15 2001     1 grey       Jan
4:  4    4    35 2001-01-22 2001     1 grey       Jan
5:  5    5    19 2001-01-29 2001     1 grey       Jan
6:  6    6    55 2001-02-05 2001     2 grey       Feb
```

I need to create a circular plot for each year. I can do this with labels for each week:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(hrbrthemes)

a<-"
id   week posts   weekdate year month  col fct_month
1     1    26 2001-01-01 2001     1 grey       Jan
2     2    24 2001-01-08 2001     1 grey       Jan
3     3    35 2001-01-15 2001     1 grey       Jan
4     4    35 2001-01-22 2001     1 grey       Jan
5     5    19 2001-01-29 2001     1 grey       Jan
6     6    55 2001-02-05 2001     2 grey       Feb
7     7    32 2001-02-12 2001     2 grey       Feb
8     8    31 2001-02-19 2001     2 grey       Feb
9     9    36 2001-02-26 2001     2 grey       Feb
10   10    36 2001-03-05 2001     3 grey       Mar
11   11    24 2001-03-12 2001     3 grey       Mar
12   12    42 2001-03-19 2001     3 grey       Mar
13   13    29 2001-03-26 2001     3 grey       Mar
14   14    57 2001-04-02 2001     4 grey       Apr
15   15    31 2001-04-09 2001     4 grey       Apr
16   16    33 2001-04-16 2001     4 grey       Apr
17   17    17 2001-04-23 2001     4 grey       Apr
18   18    16 2001-04-30 2001     4 grey       Apr
19   19    35 2001-05-07 2001     5 grey       May
20   20    23 2001-05-14 2001     5 grey       May
"
mindf<-fread(a)
ggplot(data=mindf, aes(x=factor(week), y=posts, group = year, color = col)) + 
  ylim(0,NA) +
  geom_point(, stat='identity') +
  geom_polygon(fill=NA)+
  coord_polar(start =0) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  xlab('Week of the year')+
  ylab('Job ads posted per week') +
  theme_ipsum()
```

and the result is:

[image: chart with weekly data]

but when I do it with labeling months it all fails because I guess it becomes grouped by months:

```r
ggplot(mindf, aes(x = fct_month, y = posts, 
               group = year, colour = col)) + 
  geom_line(size = .5) +
  # geom_polygon(fill=NA)+
  scale_color_identity()+
  # scale_y_discrete(expand = c(0, 1), breaks = NULL) +
  xlim(month.abb) + 
  coord_polar() +
  theme_bw() + xlab(NULL) + ylab(NULL)
```

[image: chart with monthly data]

UPDATE:

If I add
`scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b")`
as @stefan suggests below, that results in multiple months with the same name:

[image: Multiple months]

Here is the reproducible code for checking that:

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)


a<-" week posts   weekdate year month  col fct_month
    1    26 2001-01-01 2001     1 grey       Jan
    2    24 2001-01-08 2001     1 grey       Jan
    3    35 2001-01-15 2001     1 grey       Jan
    4    35 2001-01-22 2001     1 grey       Jan
    5    19 2001-01-29 2001     1 grey       Jan
    6    55 2001-02-05 2001     2 grey       Feb
    7    32 2001-02-12 2001     2 grey       Feb
    8    31 2001-02-19 2001     2 grey       Feb
    9    36 2001-02-26 2001     2 grey       Feb
   10    36 2001-03-05 2001     3 grey       Mar
    2    34 2002-01-07 2002     1 grey       Jan
    3    34 2002-01-14 2002     1 grey       Jan
    4    27 2002-01-21 2002     1 grey       Jan
    5    27 2002-01-28 2002     1 grey       Jan
    6    25 2002-02-04 2002     2 grey       Feb
    7    36 2002-02-11 2002     2 grey       Feb
    8    34 2002-02-18 2002     2 grey       Feb
    9    41 2002-02-25 2002     2 grey       Feb
   10    34 2002-03-04 2002     3 grey       Mar
   11    34 2002-03-11 2002     3 grey       Mar
"
mindf<-fread(a) %>% 
  mutate(weekdate=as.Date(weekdate, format="%Y-%m-%d"))
ggplot(data=mindf, aes(x=weekdate, y=posts, group = year, color = col)) + 
  ylim(0,NA) +
  geom_point(stat='identity') +
  geom_polygon(fill=NA, aes(group=year,color=year))+
  coord_polar(start =0) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  xlab('Week of the year')+
  ylab('Job ads posted per week') +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want month labels you could use a date scale like so:

```r
library(data.table)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)

mindf<-fread(a)
mindf$weekdate <- as.Date(mindf$weekdate)
ggplot(data=mindf, aes(x=weekdate, y=posts, group = year, color = col)) + 
  ylim(0,NA) +
  geom_point(, stat='identity') +
  geom_polygon(fill=NA)+
  coord_polar(start =0) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  xlab('Week of the year')+
  ylab('Job ads posted per week') +
  theme_ipsum()
```

[image]

**EDIT** In case of multiple years a date scale is still possible. In that case we could fix the year of the date mapped on x, which I call `monthdate` in my code:

```r
library(data.table)
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)

mindf<-fread(a)
mindf$weekdate <- as.Date(mindf$weekdate)
mindf$day <- format(mindf$weekdate, "%d")
mindf$monthdate <- as.Date(paste("2001", mindf$month, mindf$day, sep = "-"))

ggplot(data=mindf, aes(x=monthdate, y=posts, group = year, color = col)) + 
  ylim(0,NA) +
  geom_point(, stat='identity') +
  geom_polygon(fill=NA)+
  coord_polar(start =0) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%b") +
  xlab('Week of the year')+
  ylab('Job ads posted per week') +
  theme_ipsum()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! but see update. Unfortunately in this case for several years it starts repeating month names (several januaries, februaries etc)

Comment: here is an example: https://rnotebook.io/anon/98e4e50e6a102030/notebooks/circiular.ipynb

Comment: Hi Philipp. Okay. I See. Have a look at my edit. Maybe this offers a solution for your issue.

Comment: So it basically substitute year in all data to a fixed one (2001)?

Comment: Yep. As far as I get it this should work. Of course you can choose whatever year you want. (;

Comment: it works like charm, thanks a lot! Do you think it is possible to NOT connect endline and startline in polar coordinates?

Comment: Forget it! It's enough to change `geom_polygon` to `geom_line`

Comment: very minor remark: it's better to choose the leap year (2020 for instance) because otherwise this code will produce NAs in this case: `as.Date("2001-02-29", format('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: (: Yep. Had the same thought on my bike ride. One always forgets about the details when not working with the real dataset. Best S.